# How to make "prettiest" looking Counter

Tags: python

I have a list of some string words and with the collection counter I made also an frequency analisys but I do not like the way it is appearing.. How can I from this

```
[('a', 25), ('b', 20), ('C', 18), ('D', 3)]
```

make something like

```
a: 25
b: 20
C: 18 
D: 3
```

Comment: That's a list of tuples, not a `Counter` object

Comment: and, in general: write a function to do it. The function will probably use a comprehension or a loop.

Comment: well, I do not know what do you mean because I made it with something like that  most_common_words= [word for word, word_count in Counter(list_of_alphabet).most_common(len(lines))]

Comment: One of the other important questions is... Python2 or Python3?

Comment: I have Python 3

Answer (score 1):

The code you're looking for is:

```
def do_a_count(input_things):
  for key,value in input_things:
    print "%s: %d"%(key,value)
```

Comment: The `print` function syntax was changed in python 3.

Comment: Ah misse the missing parenthesis.

Comment: Also, I think that the `%` syntax for format strings was changed. Don't quote me on that one, though.

Comment: It wasn't, but you should probably use `.format` since `%` ispretty much deprecated

Answer (score 1):

Simply as:

```
x =[('a', 25), ('b', 20), ('C', 18), ('D', 3)]

for i in range(len(x)):
    print(x[i][0], ': ', x[i][1])
```